# java command no returning anything in CMD

Tags: java, windows, cmd, path, java-15

I just installed the JDK for 15.0.2 and added the bin to my path. When I type java in the command prompt, nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you add the path to the executable file to your path environment variable?

Comment: So many unanswered questions - but, at least first, close the terminal you have open, then, open a new terminal window and try the command again. It would be helpful to know the platform and how you installed the JDK.

Comment: I added the path ending in \bin

Answer (score 4):

This issue might happen when if you have multiple versions of jdk on your machine and removed one of them, or if the installation went wrong. To solve this issue just make sure of two things:

1. ***"{path to jdk}\bin"*** is added to your path. usually path is ***"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin"*** like that.
2. Make sure that Path variable in System variables has the variable ***"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"***

If all is set, then you have come to the most important step that will fix the issue. Navigate to ***"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"*** , there you will find java.exe, javac.exe..etc. now copy the java.exe from ***{path to jdk}\bin*** to this folder. do the same with the rest of executables found in ***"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"*** folder.

This solved the problem for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Installed app" in Windows and remove one of jdk versions